# How to display all windows names in the Gnome overview screen without mouse over - Ubtuntu 20.04.1

Tags: gnome, 20.04, mouse, activities-overview

In Gnome Activities overview screen, window names will be displayed only on mouse hover. But
I want to display names of the windows without hovering. How to do that in Ubuntu 20.04.1?

[image: GNOME Activities Overview screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Gnome Shell extension [Always Show Titles In Overview by 5q0Fw](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1689/always-show-titles-in-overview/).